# after wordpress migragtion : bad script owner

Tags: wordpress, permissions, migration

I used the Plug in Duplicator to perform a wordpress migration.
everything works fine, but at the end of the migration when I try to open my site, I get this error:

> bad script owner /home/0/1/dro.123.fr/www.alan-pizza-vaureal/index.php.

The rights of my FTP repository is 644.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set index.php 644 (-rw-r--r--) permissions.

Check it out WordPress docs about files permissions https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions.

Comment: It's a Shared Host or VPS?

Comment: it's a Shared host